# How to select from tableA sum of grouped numbers from tableB above their sums average in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, sum, average, subquery

I have data like this:

```
tableA.ID
---------
1
2
3

tableB.ID tableB.NUM
--------------------
1         10
1         15
2         18
3         12
2         12
2         15
3         13
1         12
```

I need to select tableA IDs where the sum of their NUMs in tableB is above the average of all tableA IDs sums. In other words:

```
SUM ID=1 -> 10+15+12 = 37
SUM ID=2 -> 18+12+15 = 45
SUM ID=3 -> 12+13    = 25

AVG ALL IDs -> (37+45+25)/3 = 35
```

The SELECT must only show ID 1 and 2 because 37 > 35, 45 > 35 but 25 < 35.

This is my current query which is working fine:

```
SELECT tableA.ID
FROM tableA, tableB
WHERE tableA.ID = tableB.ID
HAVING SUM(tableB.NUM) > (
    SELECT AVG(MY_SUM)
    FROM (
        SELECT SUM(tableB.NUM) MY_SUM
        FROM tableA, tableB
        WHERE tableA.ID = tableB.ID
        GROUP BY tableA.ID
    )
)
GROUP BY tableA.ID
```

But I have a feeling there might be a better way without all those nested SELECTs. Perhaps 2, but 3 feels like too much. I'm probably wrong though.

For instance, why can't I do something simple like this:

```
SELECT tableA.ID
FROM tableA, tableB
WHERE tableA.ID = tableB.ID
HAVING SUM(tableB.NUM) > AVG(SUM(tableB.NUM))
GROUP BY tableA.ID
```

Or this:

```
SELECT tableA.ID, SUM(tableB.NUM) MY_SUM
FROM tableA, tableB
WHERE tableA.ID = tableB.ID
HAVING MY_SUM > AVG(MY_SUM)
GROUP BY tableA.ID
```

Comment: BTW Your example data is missing a row for `2,12` I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server you can do this. Don't know if it works in Oracle. I'm sure I'll find out soon if it doesn't!

```
WITH cte As (
SELECT 
      tableA.ID, 
      SUM(tableB.NUM) AS MY_SUM, 
      AVG(SUM(tableB.NUM)) over() As Average
FROM tableA, tableB
WHERE tableA.ID = tableB.ID
GROUP BY tableA.ID
)
SELECT ID 
FROM cte 
WHERE MY_SUM > Average
```

Comment: @Nazgulled - It avoids doing the `JOIN` twice though (at least in theory, I have absolutely no idea if it is supported in Oracle and how it would be implemented if it is)

Comment: It worked on my example database. Can I assume it's not joining twice or that might still not be true? And what exactly does `OVER()` do?

Comment: @Nazgulled - The empty `OVER()` clause calculates an aggregate over the whole (unpartitioned) result. You're probably better off looking at the execution plans to determine which of the various options is most efficient.

Answer (score 1):

This should reduce it by one level

```
SELECT tableA.ID
FROM tableA, tableB
WHERE tableA.ID = tableB.ID
GROUP BY tableA.ID
HAVING SUM(tableB.NUM) > (
    SELECT SUM(tableB.NUM)/COUNT(DISTINCT tableA.ID)
    FROM tableA, tableB
    WHERE tableA.ID = tableB.ID
)
```

Comment: Forget about AVG() then? It looks like a good solution... I'll just wait a few more hours to see if anyone comes up with any good alternatives.